# Top horizontal alignment on float right

Tags: css, css-float

This is driving me mental.
Why wont my third div (content-col-text) not go up on float right?
It stays aligned to the gallery-thumb-container? I need it to go to the right and up and align with large-image-container - this is where the outer div wrapper is (entry-content)..

I dont have any weird margin stuff going on even..

[image: floating div example]

Comment: Why not switch their positions? put `content-col-text` on the second.

Comment: i think all you need to do is put the content-col-text div above the gallery-thumb-container div :)

Comment: Yes - it was the order thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your order is not correct. You need to change it as below for it to work.

Below is the code:

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="large-image-container">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="content-col-text">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="gallery-thumb-container">&nbsp;</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.large-image-container{float:left; width:66%; background:red;}
.gallery-thumb-container{float:left; width:66%; background:yellow;}
.content-col-text{float:right; width:31%; background:green;}
```

**The Fiddle demo:**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ubwmgLwp/)**

Usually, under such circumstances, when you use a `clear:both;`, the floats get corrected and it works properly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: could you post your fiddle?

Comment: Yes with the text div as the second it works - ty :)

Answer (score 1):

your `gallery-thumb-container` has probably been forced down as it floats left and there's no more space to the right of `large-image-container`.

You could try switching the order of the `<div>`'s and put `content-col-text` second instead of third

Another option would be to position it absolutely, but that will take it out of the flow of the document...

Comment: yeah ok - you guys were right. the order of course helped - ty!